# How to Remove a Non Tag Html Element using NodeJs?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have a HTML string like this:

```html
<div>
   <p>a</p>
   <p>b</p>
   <p>c</p>
   <img src='a.jpg'>
   <img src='b.jpg'>
   d
   e
   f
</div>
```

I have used [sanitize-html](https://github.com/punkave/sanitize-html) to allow only tag p and img, however, it still return all text.

The last result that I want is to remove d, e and f like below:

```html
<div>
   <p>a</p>
   <p>b</p>
   <p>c</p>
   <img src='a.jpg'>
   <img src='b.jpg'>
</div>
```

Here is my code using sanitizeHtml:

```
var htmlString = sanitizeHtml(news.htmlcontent, {
    allowedTags: [ 'p', 'img' ],
    exclusiveFilter: function(frame) {
        return (frame.tag === 'img' && frame.attribs.src.indexOf('rfa_resources/graphics') !== -1);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In your specific case where code is between `<div>` tags, so the following example removes the unwanted text.

```js
var sanitizeHtml = require('sanitize-html');

var HTMLstring = "<div><p>a</p><p>b</p><p>c</p><img src='a.jpg'><img src='b.jpg'>def</div>";

var sanitizedString = sanitizeHtml(HTMLstring, {
    allowedTags: [ 'p', 'img', 'div' ],
    exclusiveFilter: function(frame) {
        return (frame.tag === 'img' && frame.attribs.src.indexOf('rfa_resources/graphics') !== -1);
    },
    transformTags: {
        'div': function(tagName) {
            return {
                tagName: 'div',
                text: ''
            };
        }
    },
});

console.log(sanitizedString); // <div><p>a</p><p>b</p><p>c</p><img src="a.jpg" /><img src="b.jpg" /></div>
```

Comment: It depends on the tags that you want to have their text removed. What are the tags that you want to have their text removed?

Answer (score 0):

Those who are seeking to achive same using jquery, following is the code which helps to do so:

```
function getText(str){
    $('body').append('<section id="test"></section>');
    $('#test').append(str);
    var text = $("#test div").contents().filter(function() {
      return this.nodeType == 3;
    }).text();
    $('#test').remove();
    return text;
}
var myString = "<div><p>a</p><p>b</p><p>c</p><img src='a.jpg'><img src='b.jpg'>def</div>";
var text = getText(myString);
var result = myString.replace(text, '');
console.log(result); // <div><p>a</p><p>b</p><p>c</p><img src='a.jpg'><img src='b.jpg'></div>
```

But please pay attention that all text nodes should appear together otherwise code will need little modification to remove all of them.

*I hope it helps...*